# Can I use different nameservers for different subdomains?

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain, nameserver, dns-servers

Suppose I have `example.com` and the nameserver I'm using is the one from the hosting server where I'm hosting the main site, say `mainhosting.com`.

Now suppose I add a new subdomain e.g. `bla.example.com` which I'm hosting somewhere else, say at `subhosting.org`.

This typically requires editting the DNS settings at `mainhosting.com`, adding an A record for `bla.example.com` to resolve to the webserver's IP address at `subhosting.org`.

Is it also possible to set things up so `bla.example.com` (but only the subdomain, *not* the entire `example.com` domain) is using `subhosting.org`'s nameserver instead? So whenever the IP address for `subhosting.org`'s webserverver changes, it can be updated automatically.

I mean the webhoster at `subhosting.org` can typically update any relevant DNS settings for their own webservers automatically, but obviously this doesn't work when I'm using an external nameserver (and thus the DNS records are configured externally).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, You can.

you will have to add the NS records for the subdomain in the DNS Manager for your TLD (Top Level Domain).

For Example:
In DNS Manager for TLD add NS records Like.

```
bla.example.com. 1799 IN    NS  ns1.subhosting.org.
bla.example.com. 1799 IN    NS  ns3.subhosting.org.
bla.example.com. 1799 IN    NS  ns2.subhosting.org.
```

Answer (score -4):

In short no.

Your TLD records have to be on the same nameserver. The DNS lookup first tries to find your main domain - then gets the records in order to determine what to do with the request. It's only after this it processes the subdomain. You can direct different subdomains to different IPs (servers) but you can't force a client to keep looking at name servers for additional records. The client will take the first it finds.

Comment: What's stopping you from creating NS records for the subdomain `bla` in the DNS zone at `mainhosting.com` that point to `subhosting.com`s nameservers (apart from the fact that many _high-level DNS control panels_ don't actually allow you to do this)? See [this answer on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/a/275998/49157).