# How do I point a subdomain to a different nameserver use Google Domains?

Tags: domains, wordpress, dns, dns-servers, google-domains

I discovered this question:
[Can I use different nameservers for different subdomains?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93897/can-i-use-different-nameservers-for-different-subdomains)

And I tried it out using Google domains.

I currently have a site hosted with AWS. However, I'd like to use Siteground to host a subdomain.

How can I do this through Google domains? According to the answer I posted, you just have to update an NS record on Google domains with the desired subdomain name and the nameserver. However, I tried this and it is not working.

For example, in Google domains I'm using 5 AWS nameservers:

```
ns2.aws.org
ns3.aws.org
ns4.aws.org
ns5.aws.org
```

and in the custom resource records section, I have a NS record set up like this:

```
Name    Type    TTL     Data
dev     NS      5m      ns1.siteground.us
                        ns2.siteground.us
```

On siteground, I have a WordPress site installed on the dev.mysite.com domain

What else do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: "you just have to update an NS record on Google domains with the desired subdomain name and the nameserver. "  ... and you have to configure (or make someone configure) properly the nameservers to which you delegate the zone, so you have 2 things to do, on different sides, and without both it won't work. However like Stephen said, you probably do not need all of that. Just put the proper `A`/`AAAA`  or `CNAME` records for `dev` pointing to your wehbost, and you are all set.

Comment: The question you linked has the answer you need.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are in the Google Domains control panel you can select name servers from the menu and it allows you to set up to twelve different name servers.

[image: Google Domains name servers]

If you want a subdomain on a different host, you normally do that with a CNAME or A Record. Google Domains actually makes this really easy, just type in your subdomain and set your hosts IP address.
[image: Google Domains Registered Host/subdomain]

Personally, I don't think you need the name server change if all you want is to set a subdomain, blog.example.com. You just need a IP address for your Siteground server.