# How to point subdomain to AWS Amplify?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns

I have domain registered on porkbun suppose example.com
I have landing page hosted on `wix.com`,from which I used their nameservers in porkbun's setting and `www.example.com` is working fine.
Now I have parts of site hosted `aws amplfiy`, so I want to make `home.example.com` load the amplify content.
How can I do that?

What I tried already:

1. When I try to add subdomain in amplify setting it gives me 2 values to set like following in porkbun's dns setting.

   `_3abbe162eeb3ca7211b8c5a659cab5a3    CNAME    _2de7d1ffc9c8a9aa1573634f0bfe21d8.bsgbmzkfwj.acm-validations.aws.`

   `_3abbe162eeb3ca7211b8c5a659cab5a3    CNAME    _2de7d1ffc9c8a9aa1573634f0bfe21d8.bsgbmzkfwj.acm-validations.aws.`

   Which did not work,as I was not able to reach home.example.com
2. Saw this question,which I think is exactly what I want
   [Can I use different nameservers for different subdomains?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93897/can-i-use-different-nameservers-for-different-subdomains?newreg=23538c4fe82343ada2cf28b2c0704a5c)

   But I am not sure how to get A record for home.example.com from amplify hosting.
   And its solution suggets adding nameserver in dns manager of TLD (porkbun here I suppose),but I dont have amplfify nameserver.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [AWS Amplify documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/custom-domains.html) only talks about running the service on the base domain name.  It doesn't indicate that it is possible to run it on a subdomain.

Comment: Their documentation says that you should use [AWS Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) as your "Amplify nameserver".   I'm not sure if that would make it possible to run Amplify on a subdomain though.

Comment: In addition to the validation DNS records that you implemented you should have a cloudfront subdomain where you can point a CNAME record for `@` and the `www.` subdomain.   Have you tried pointing your `home` subdomain to that?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller you can't have both a cname for "@" and for a subdomain (at least not in the same zone"

Comment: Their documentation actually shows an a name not a c name for the domain apex

Answer (score 1):

You can use different nameservers for different subdomains.  See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807814/different-name-servers-for-different-subdomains

To point a subdomain to another server, here are a couple of methods.

In your hosting panel (e.g. cpanel) create the subdomain `home.example.com`.  Then in DNS find the `A Record` for that and change the IP address to the IP address of the amplify server.

Alternatively, in DNS, create an `A Record` for the subdomain and set the IP address.  Both methods have the same outcome.

You then must have `home.example.com` set up on the target server.

Comment: For adding A record in hosting panel(here I suppose wix where root domain is hosted),I dont have ip address of amplify,but only values mentioned in question.

Comment: You absolutely can use different name servers for subdomains - and the whole DNS structure is predicated on this. That's what NS records do.

Comment: Thanks @davidgo, I learned something and have updated my answer