# Manage multiple subdomain on a different nameserver?

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain, nameserver, dns-servers

I have a domain, `example.com` which is managed on Cloudflare, and I would like to manage multiple sub-sub-domains, that end with `.internal.example.com`, such as `one.one.internal.example.com` and `two.internal.example.com` on route53, while still managing `example.com` and the rest on Cloudflare.

According to [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93897/can-i-use-different-nameservers-for-different-subdomains?newreg=5f6ba788c2144197a079711efffd1d8e), I understand it's possible to manage one sub-domain on different nameservers, but how do I manage multiple sub-sub-domains?

Am I forced to create a nameserver entry on the TLD (Top Level Domain) for every sub-sub-domain or can I use a wildcard or some other method to only add one nameserver entry on the TLD?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, all you have to do is add records like these on your TLD, as the original question suggested:

```
internal.example.com. 1799 IN    NS  ns1.second-nameserver.org.
internal.example.com. 1799 IN    NS  ns2.second-nameserver.org.
```

After that, any DNS entry that ends with `.internal.example.com`, such as `one.one.internal.example.com` or `two.internal.example.com` can be managed by the second nameserver, no extra configuration needed.